# How to get balance of an address using web3js

Tags: web3js-v1.x

Here is a very simple code that i am using :-

```
    let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXX"));
    var balance;
    web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1").then(bal => balance = bal);
    document.write(balance + "<BR>");
```

And it gives me the output `undefined`. So i decided to wait for 5 seconds before printing the output.

```
    function sleep(miliseconds) {
       var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    
       while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
       }
    }
    let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/XXXXX"));
    var balance;
    web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1").then(bal => balance = bal);
    sleep(5000);
    document.write(balance + "<BR>");
```

This waits for 5 seconds and the output is still `undefined`. What is the proper way to store the result of promise in an external variable?

I don't want to print the result inside the `.then(bal => document.write(bal));`

Comment: "I don't want to print the result inside the `.then(bal => document.write(bal));`" - but that's your one and only option. This result is retrieved from another process, therefore, asynchronously of your process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `async/await` pattern :

```
const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1");
```

Comment: So i have written this :- `async function ffuu() {    document.write("Something");
            const bl = await web3.eth.getBalance("0x407d73d8a49eeb85d32cf465507dd71d507100c1");
            document.write(bl + "<BR>");
        }` 

but the output is just `something` and then nothing prints